# How to correctly position an image above another image, without the originally set image's wrapper height?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to position the icon in the bottom right corner of an image. There is a wrapper, where images with different sizes should fit. And there is an img-wrapper, that include image and icon.

The problem is that it requires to specify 100% height for the img-wrapper, which is also a parent block for an icon, so it turns out to be at the bottom of this block and not the image. img tag also doesn't support ::after pseudoelement.

Is there a way to position the icon correctly without bringing js?

Example: codepen.io/girich1/pen/YzrQaVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you'll just need 1 more little wrapper to hold the icon(s).

Add a `<div class="imgicons">` around both the `img.icon` lines:

```
  <div class="imgicons">
    <img class="icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/verified-badge.png"/>
  </div>
```

Next, remove your current `.icon { ... }` section from your CSS. And add the following instead:

```
.imgicons {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  top: -30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

That should get you what you want if i understood it correctly.

*(fyi: the icon is `20px`; i presumed you'd want say a `10px` padding compared to the bottom right corner, added together that makes `30px`; which is what that `-30px` refers to)*

Comment: wow, this wrapper for icon really did a thing, thank you very much!